# can I upload user's profile image via data loader

Tags: administration, data-loader, configuration

I have a several user photos, is there a way of uploading them to the user's profiles en mass?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can upload profile photos in Bulk as per current salesforce functionality. 
There is already an idea link
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HA1nAAG

There is a free app exchange application called Photo Uploader which might be helpful as well