# Need to upload photo for a User from Apex Rest and show it on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, apexrest

My requirement is as follows (please note both the things I have to do programmatically)
1. To upload a profile photo for an user
2. And then make the image available for user/other users to view on that user's profile page.

For the first requirement, my approach was to create an Attachment with parent-Id as the User's ID for whom a picture attachment have been created.

But unfortunately, User record can't have an attachment. However, User have contact object reference and contact can have an attachment. (this I did to achieve feature one). Limitation for this approach is, I have to create a Contact and Account object.

Now to show the image on user's profile, I created a custom formula field (in User object) which uses the uploaded attachment's id [can be reached through contact reference present in User object] to show the image on User's profile.

This question is to just validate the approach or if there is any better approach for Photo upload for user.

Comment: Are you trying to update their profile photo? Are these actually community users?

Comment: If User, look at the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/) for User. there are several fields that need updated including `FullPhotoUrl` and `SmallPhotoUrl`. It doesn't become an attachment.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Users would be standard users and these users would be created first and then photo for them would be uploaded using Apex rest api.

Comment: @crmprogdev I checked these fields (`FullPhotoUrl` and `SmallPhotoUrl`) but am not sure how to use these fields programmatically (using Apex to upload the photo and use these fields).

Comment: Wherever you upload/save these files to, the URL needs to be saved in the `FullPhotoUrl` field. There's a size limit for display in profiles on an image. If you're resizing images, after resizing &saving to another location, set the `SmallPhotoUrl`. If the file satisfies the size requirement, set both fields to where you're saving it.

Comment: @crmprogdev But it seems these fields are readonly, got error "Field is not writeable"

Comment: If it's profile photo, you must use the `ConnectApi`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have an answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/95140/2995).

> You could use the new [Connect API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm).
>
> Specifically the [ChatterUsers Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_static_methods.htm) with the [setPhoto method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterUsers_setPhoto_2).