# Access ConnectApi's setPhoto method on UserProfiles when the current user is a guest user

Tags: trigger, community, chatter, future, chatter-api

Currently we are using a custom self registration page on community to allow users to register for the community. As a part of this registration process, we want to assign a default profile picture to the user which is different from the one provided by Salesforce chatter.

When I try to update the profile picture using setPhoto method of ConnectApi in user trigger, I get an error.

```
Guest user does not have access to this method.
```

I have tried using `@future`methods and also tried using `without sharing` on apex trigger. Chatter methods executing based on the current users context regardless of the execution context is causing the issue here.

If anyone faced a similar issue and have figured out the solution to this, please post an answer.

Basically, my goal here is to be able to set the profile picture of the user to a default pic when they sign up using the self registration form.
Thanks.

Comment: Post your full code to better assist

Comment: Controller for component : [CustomCommunitiesSelfRegController](http://pastebin.com/HakfMvzg)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I currently dont have the userTrigger code with me,but  when the user is inserted, the following is method is called `ConnectApi.UserProfiles.setPhoto(communityId, userId, fileId, versionNumber)`

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Found it. Here is the [UserHandler](http://pastebin.com/xJFsPMmY) class for the User Trigger.

Comment: @KarthikeyaPammi : Guest don't have Profile Pics, that's why you are not able to call `setPhoto` method. Do you want to give default photo to new user being created ?\

Comment: @Ankuli Yeah. Thats true. When they sign up using Community Self registration page, we create a user for them through a `@AuraEnabled` method. So when I am inserting the user, the current user is Guest user. Hence any ConnectApi methods i run in the trigger use Guest User Permissions. So how do I set the photo of the new User?

Comment: try this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70549/how-can-i-upload-change-users-profile-image-programatically-or-via-api

Comment: @Ankuli Thanks for sharing the link. However, I already tried using setPhoto. But in my case I have run this method as a guest user. Is there something I am missing here? Can this be done?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Hey! I was thinking of launching scheduled apex job from the trigger. Is that a good approach? Kindly share your views